# SSIS: How to deal with file paths in SSIS tasks and in the files themselves when going from a Dev server to a Prod server

Tags: ssis

**Situation:**

- I have a number of Process Tasks that point to files, like PowerShell files, or .bat files on a specific Dev Server location.  Something like \DEV_Server\Files
- When I'm ready to deploy the package to a Prod server, I'll need all the paths changed (in the files themselves and in the SSIS tasks) to point to a Prod server location.  Something like \PROD_Server\Files

**Concern:**

- There can be so many tasks/files/locations to change that it leaves a lot of room to miss one (file path in .bat/.ps1 file themselves or file path in a Process Task) and have the PROD package point to a DEV location somewhere.

**Questions:**

1. How would you typically handle this to reduce the chances of missing a file path, either in the .bat/.ps1 files themselves or the file path on the SSIS Task?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should make all your paths as variable parameters. For Flat File Source you can do that in `Connection Manager > Properties > Expressions > Connection String`.

If strucutre of PROD and DEV are the same, all path variables could also be defined as expressions, deriving from single variable containing base path. Then you would only need to change this variable to switch between PROD and DEV.

Also, read about [Environments](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables). You can run deployed packages using different environments, where among other things you can define different values for variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd organize my paths properly, on DEV as in PROD and manage them using the [SSIS catalog environments](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/).

The values saved in the environments are mapped to the package parameters (via package configuration), I use it for pretty much anything that can be considered a parameter or that may change (connection strings, paths, etc) since I might not want to rebuild and deploy the whole project just because the files have been moved.

in the below image you can see that I've mapped the path to single scripts (because I've got just 5), but if you have lots of them just map the root folder or a folder up to a certain level.

[image]

This of course means that you will have to properly build your paths in the SSIS project, concatenating the path coming from a parameter + the script name using expressions.

About how to avoid issues, the best way for me is just to have a clear structure, possibly the same for DEV and PROD. If everything is properly parametrized and a non-existing path is used the package will (should?) fail...

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni Luisotto!  You mentioned package parameters, but in your screenshot, I see 'Variables'.  When you create a package parameter, does SSIS create it as a variable?

Comment: @JM1 In the environment you have variables, but the name is not important...  in the SSIS package, you have project parameters, package parameters, and variables. once a package is deployed to the server you can reference and environment, and map whatever param you have to an existing variable in the environment

Answer (score 0):

Lots of correct answers already here, but I'd like to make a couple of additional points.

First, following on @GiovanniLuisotto 's comment:

> About how to avoid issues, the best way for me is just to have a clear
> structure, possibly the same for DEV and PROD. If everything is
> properly parametrized and a non-existing path is used the package will
> (should?) fail...

Keep it simple - if possible, make dev and prod the same.  So, instead of `c:\Dev_server\Files`, use `c:\Tools\Files`.  This also means that drive and path names should be the same on each server.

If you're pointing to a share, then make that the only thing that needs to be configured.  `\\DevBox\Files` gets configured to an expression like: `"\\\\" + @[$Project::Parameter] + "\\Files"`.  So you would only have a single parameter with the server name and that's the only parameter you need.

For the .bat and .ps1 files, use relative paths.  If, for some reason, this needs to point to a share or external resource, this should be converted into a parameter in the script.  That can get complicated if some scripts need it and other's don't.  Those can be separated as two different script types.  Relative paths or at least consistent paths are the best way to go.